# how to download json object in file asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i have class

```
    class abc{
       [JsonPropertyName("firstName")]
       public string FirstName{get; set;}

       [JsonPropertyName("lastName")]
       public string LastName{get; set;} }
```

i am assigning some values in it one method.

```
     public void DownloadJson(){
     abc abcModel= new abc(){ FirstName="Tom", LastName="Torres"};

     var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abcModel);
     }
```

i want to save(download) this test object in json file on my browserwithout directing in new window just simply download it in same method DownloadJson() and in current window.

Comment: Is this asp.net core? Are you using MVC? Please provide more details. Otherwise it is too much infer.

Comment: yes it is .net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked.

```
   fileName="xyz.json"

   byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);

   var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
   return File(content , "application/json", fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ContentResult DownloadJson(){
 var builder = new StringBuilder();
 abc abcModel= new abc(){ FirstName="Tom", LastName="Torres"};
 var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abcModel);
 builder.Append($"{test}")
 var fileName = "someName.JSON";

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{fileName}\"");

        return Content(data, "text/plain");

 }
```

have you tried returning a ContentResult?

Comment: Why not return Json(abcModel)?